# while integrating s3 with ckfinder3 it shows ckfinder/connector url not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, ckeditor, ckfinder

update ckfinder 2 to 3 and install packages using NuGet but while image browse in ckeditor it returns 404 error showing connector URL not found

Comment: You have to map the connector under this path in your application, like `app.Map("/ckfinder/connector", SetupConnector);`. Please have a look at this [step by step guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/integration.html#integration_existing_application) for details.

Comment: i installed it through nuget packages so i dont think that to use app.map connector.